# Discord.js : reaction.message.guild.members.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord.js bot that add the "Joueur" role to the user who reacted with the ✅ emoji. I am new to JS and I found the `reaction.message.guild.members.find` function on the Internet but I somehow get the error `TypeError: reaction.message.guild.members.find is not a function` and the role is not added.
Here is the part of my code :

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
      try {
        reaction.message.guild.members.find('id', user.id).addRole(reaction.message.guild.roles.find('name', 'Joueur'));
      } catch {
        console.log('Error : can\'t add the role');
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Discord.js v12 (the latest version), [`Guild#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) is a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager), not a `Collection` like in v11.

To access the collection use the `cache` property.

Another difference is that `Collection` does not support finding something by key and value like that. However, it does support getting objects by its `id`:

```js
reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
```

Note that to find an object by another key, you would need to use this:

```js
reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.someProperty === theValue)
```

---

You might also want to check that the reaction was done in a guild (unless you're using intents and aren't using the `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent). People can add reactions to messages in DMs as well, so `reaction.message.guild` may be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version, here is an example:

They have also changed addRole to: roles.add in v12

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'somerolename');
reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.add(role.id).catch(console.error);
```

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#roles

Answer (score -1):

According to the [doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=handleCollect), you can use `reaction.users` to get a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of users who reacted to the message.
The collection will look something like this:

```
Collection(n)[Map] {
    'id_of_user_who_reacted' => <ref*1> ClientUser{
        id: 'id_of_user_who_reacted',
        username: String,
        discriminator:String
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use the **map()** method of the Collector type to get the user id

```js
console.log(reaction.users.map(user => user.id))
```

which will return an array that will look like this:
`['id', 'id', 'id']`
Then you can change the role of those users.