# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Purpose:**

To ban members ID's from an array in a `json` file

**Code:**

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'idfk')){
            const IDs = require("./IDs.json")

            message.guild.member(IDs).ban({
                reason: "testing",
            })
        }
```

*`IDs.json`* contains an array of IDs.

**Error:**

```
(node:5420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null
```

Could you please tell me why this is happening what I could do to solve it?

Comment: `message.guild.member(IDs)` is returning `null`. _Probably_ this method allows an unique ID, while you're passing an array of IDs. Look at documentation what `member()` allows as parameter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455173/discord-js-reaction-message-guild-members-find-is-not-a-function could help?

Comment: [`Guild#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) expects a [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) as a parameter. Not an array of id's.

Comment: What about [Guild#members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) / `Guild#MemberManager` ??

Comment: What about it? As described in the post Giovannil linked, you can use it to find the elements. But if you have an array, you need to loop over it to ban each member separately.

Answer (score 0):

[ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) can be applied to [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), not ID. You only have IDs array, loop through the ids array, and get the Member object using the id, and the apply ban command. An example code would be something like:

```
....
IDs.forEach(function(memberID) {
    // get the member
    const member = message.guild.members.get(memberID);
    if( member ) {
        member.ban({reason: 'testing'});
    }
});
....
```